# Laravel error on server with forge when sending email 'using $this in object context'

Tags: php, email, laravel, server, laravel-forge

I'm using Laravel forge and I have a cron job scheduled to send email reminders. Locally it works nicely but on the production server this happens at the end of each email causing the job to loop thinking it failed and thus sending countless emails ( i set a limit to re run of jobs thought :p )
Here is the message:

```
[2015-01-31 07:28:09] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Using $this when not in object context' in /home/forge/bloblo.com/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Jeremeamia/SuperClosure/SerializableClosure.php(99) : eval()'d code:19
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

Any idea ot what this comes from ? I don't understand that erorr, it in in a vendor package form laravel... 
Email template has no html tags but that should ot be a problem...

Thanks,

Comment: Try to switch host to development mode in /bootstrap/app.php to get the backtraces? Then switch back to production.

Also, do you understand that composer is CVS like the git? Both are CVS which may create the mess because composer update executed at development and production hosts may fetch different versions of libraries. Make sure the OS and php libraries fetched by composer are matching versions.

Comment: thanks, I think I found the cause! I had a $this->info() in the queued job and I think that caused the problem. not to myself to log infos in the queued job ... :-) 
for the composer it's ok, I git the .lock to keep both at the same versions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a $this->info('bla') in the queue creating an error. Remonde the console log from the queue and put it before/after.